# Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9, php-8.1

I am trying to Seed a database using a Model Factory in Laravel but am seeing this error on the terminal.

```bash
$ php artisan tinker

Psy Shell v0.11.8 (PHP 8.1.0 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Parking::factory(1)->create();
[!] Aliasing 'Parking' to 'App\Models\Parking' for this Tinker session.
TypeError: Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\wamp64\www\my-valet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 1010
```

From the multiple solutions I have tried, it seems the issue is at the faker-generated content level, but I need that faker content for the factory to work as intended.

Below are the Factory and Migration classes that will help you when trying to find the solution.

Here is my factory class

```php
class ParkingFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Parking::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->words(2),
            'description' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'spaces' => rand(10, 100),
            'physical_location' => $this->faker->streetAddress,
            'latlng' => $this->faker->localCoordinates,

            'base_pay' => $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 200),
            'base_pay_breakdown' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'rate_per_minute' => $this->faker->numberBetween(2, 10),
            'overnight_base_pay' => $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 200),
            'overnight_base_pay_breakdown' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'overnight_rate_per_minute' => $this->faker->numberBetween(2, 10),
            'other_charges_base_pay' => $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 200),
            'other_charges_base_pay_breakdown' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'other_charges_rate_per_minute' => $this->faker->numberBetween(2, 10),

            'has_disability_accessibility' => $this->faker->boolean,
            'has_other_charges' => $this->faker->boolean(1),
            'has_overnight_parking' => $this->faker->boolean,
            'overnight_charge_type' => $this->faker->randomElement(['none', 'flat', 'minute', 'both']),

//            'owner_id' => User::factory()->create(),

            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is the migration for the Parking table

```php
Schema::create('parkings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->mediumText('description');
            $table->string('code')
                ->nullable();
            $table->integer('spaces');
            $table->string('physical_location')
                ->nullable();
            $table->string('latlng')->nullable();


            //charges info
            $table->decimal('base_pay')
                ->default(0.00);
            $table->string('base_pay_breakdown')
                ->nullable();
            $table->decimal('rate_per_minute')
                ->default(0.00);
            $table->decimal('overnight_base_pay')
                ->default(0.00);
            $table->string('overnight_base_pay_breakdown')
                ->nullable();
            $table->decimal('overnight_rate_per_minute')
                ->default(0.00);
            $table->decimal('other_charges_base_pay')
                ->default(0.00);
            $table->string('other_charges_base_pay_breakdown')
                ->nullable();
            $table->decimal('other_charges_rate_per_minute')
                ->default(0.00);
            //charges info end


            $table->boolean('has_disability_accessibility')
                ->default(false);
            $table->boolean('has_other_charges')
                ->default(false);
            $table->boolean('has_overnight_parking')
                ->default(true);
            $table->string('overnight_charge_type')
                ->default('none'); //flat | minute | both
            $table->string('status')
                ->default('active');


            $table->foreignId( 'owner_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->constrained('users')
                ->nullOnDelete();


            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

It is worth noting am using Laravel `v9.24.0`, PHP `v8.1.0`, and MySQL `v8.0.27`.

What might be the cause of my error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `name` field of your table is defined as a `string`, however, the [`words`](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/text-and-paragraphs/#words) method of faker returns an `array`.

Supplying the `words` method with `true` as a second argument will return two words as a string.

```
'name' => $this->faker->words(2, true);
```

Comment: Thank you. setting `asText` to true worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->faker->words(2)
```

Generates 2 words in an array, which isn't accepted as valid param when you're trying to insert it into the db.

```
[
    "omnis",
    "sequi",
]
```

Either serialize it using `implode` function, or do it any other way.